# Rewriting a question, what’s next?

Tags: support

[A question of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/497570/what-are-the-basics-of-taking-care-for-a-common-server) has been claused as “not a real question”. It was in fact too broad, so I have rewritten it to make it better answerable. What now? The FAQ says that it will be reopened if five people do vote so, but I fear a qestion marked as closed and having received negative votes will never ever receive enaugh attraction to be reopened. Or am I wrong?

This question is not addressed by the FAQ by now. In the section “Why are some questions closed?”, there is a link at the end of the “not a real question” point, *For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ*, but that link is pointing back to the section “Why are some questions closed?” only.

I would like to talk about here:

- Does it need feedback to those who closed down a question if much of it was rewritten? And what would mean „much“ then? If this is already the case, shouldn’t it be mentioned in the article?
- Or does the negative vote needs to be forgotten automatically then?
- Is asking to rewrite a question at all a good idea? The comments will turn less understandable if the question has changed. Would it be better to ask the people to write a completely new question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When someone edits their own closed question it it automatically fed into the [/review/reopen](https://serverfault.com/review/reopen) queue where people with >3k reputation ca vote to reopen or leave closed as they see fit.

At some point in the (possibly not too distant) future the way that closed questions are handled is going to change so that it is more obvious that an OP has an opportunity to correct their question and get it reopened.

Comment: What about when someone else salvages the question? Very relevant to @tombull's [answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/5392/152073) and syneticon-dj's comment.

Comment: @AndrewB: Erm, no idea.

Comment: @AndrewB The question goes into the reopen queue regardless of who edits it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this question should be reopened. At the risk of being called hostile, my take on a question such as this is that it could be rephrased as  "take all your years of study, training, and experience, and condense it to a check list".

It really is way too broad to fit in a QA-format as SF is. This is a good place to ask for help in **how** to do a thing. It's not really a place to ask **what** to do, unless if it's in a very narrow context - which this isn't.

Comment: Agreed - This is not really a question that can be answered on Server Fault - it's something you'd learn in a 2-3 year apprenticeship under a senior systems administrator where you learn the care and feeding of `X` (where `X` is the OS and installed "stuff").

Answer (score 2):

If at least one person votes to reopen the question it will show up in the reopen queue.

See review at the top of the site and then look at the [reopen](http://meta.serverfault.com/review/reopen) option. It should get enough attention from there.

Answer (score 2):

Posting on the meta site will get it looked at by a number of users. It depends on if they thing it should be re-opened or not.

You can use the "flag" link at the bottom to flag for moderator attention and use the "other" field to request that the question is re-opened.

Difference between mod re-opening and user re-opening is that it take 5 users with sufficent priveledges to re-open the question, while a mod can do it by theirself.

I still honestly think the question covers too broad an area, so I would not cast a re-open vote if I was able to do so.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the idea of bothering the mods with things which the community can handle all by itself. Mods are meant to be ["human exception handlers"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and have enough flags to handle as it is.